# VS code terminal : Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, command-prompt, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I created a virtual environment in python, now while activating the same from my command line in vscode I am getting the error

```
PS C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\WebDev\ReactComplete\DjangoReact\ArticlesApp\APIProject> ..\venv\scripts\activate    
..\venv\scripts\activate : File C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\WebDev\ReactComplete\DjangoReact\ArticlesApp\venv\scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running 
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ..\venv\scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

This is my project structure

[image]

However if I activate the same from my command line, it works without any error.

Python version : 3.9.2

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+Activate.ps1+cannot+be+loaded+because+running++scripts+is+disabled+on+this+system

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A way is changing the terminal in VSCode to Command Prompt instead of PowerShell.

1. Open the drop-down on the right of the terminal and choose `Select Default Profile`
   [image: 1]
2. Select Command Prompt from the options.
   [image]

Or, you can also set the execution policy to `RemoteSigned` or `Unrestricted` in PowerShell

Note: This only affects the current user

1. Open PowerShell
2. Run the following command: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` OR `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`

(Remove `-Scope CurrentUser` to apply to all users)